# Desktop icons without "Desktop Folders"

Tags: desktop, icons

I wanted the facility to have icons on the desktop. The solutions I've read so far all involve downloading a utility from the App Center called Desktop Folders. It seems that utility is not available for the version of Elementary I have (6.1 Jólnir). Please help. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You can always ask the developer to port the app to elementary OS 6 here: https://github.com/spheras/desktopfolder/issues

Sadly, it seems like the developer is inactive and the project was abandoned.